# Is Superman affected by muscle loss by staying on earth's lower gravity for too long?

Tags: dc, superman

So, people can only stay on the Internation Space Station for months at a time because of the fear that the lack of gravity can affect their bone density and muscle loss.

Does this affect Superman for staying on Earth which has much less gravity than Krypton?

If he were to fight other Krytonians living in a planet that has similar environment as Kryton will he lose the fight?

Just curious.

Comment: This is also related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17121/does-superman-have-to-work-out-to-keep-in-shape

Comment: @Richard and MajorStackings, Okay that answers my question. Should have looked for the answer before asking. Would it be best for me to delete this question or leave it?

Comment: I've closed as the dupe of the second part. I'll leave @MajorStackings comment as a signpost for the first part.