# Even with his powers, doesn't Superman train and work out?

Tags: dc, comics, superman

Part of the reason **Superman** doesn't always get the respect he deserves is because people find he is both "over powered", and thus things are never a challenge for him, and that he has things "too easy" with all his abilities. More respect is given to warriors like **Batman** [who had to *hard earn* all of his peak human abilities], **Wonder Woman** [a warrior who has trained since childhood] and especially *other* super powered world protectors, like **Goku** [possibly the greatest fictional martial artist ever, and in many ways a Superman homage/analog].

The basic idea/ joke is this:

[image]

But... this isn't necessarily true, is it?

For one, Clark spent **literal years** training himself in the use of his powers. In all versions [Golden, Silver, Bronze, Modern, Post-Crisis, New 52] Clark mentions practicing or training, almost daily, to better control and refine his powers, even subconsciously. Mind you, this is done to become more *proficient* with these abilities, yes... but more so to *keep them in check* so that he doesn't hurt someone or cause random property damage with a simple touch.

Still counts as training, though...

[image]

Secondly, he's been known to somehow "depower" himself and train with Batman and Wild Cat in fighting. And he has *definitely* sparred regularly with Wonder Woman, at or near full power, because she is one of the few beings whom he can cut a little loose with and not hurt. She's trained him in hand to hand and armed combat, seen here....

[image]

and here...

[image]

and here...

[image]

and here....

[image]

To be fair, this is all sparring or fight training, so it's more "skill building" than "physical training for gains", though. It's still *important* yes, but not quite the same as "building more strength, stamina, power, speed, etc". Nor is either of them pushing their limits, so it seems.

Unless one counts his training in the Kryptonian Torqasm arts---- which are more akin to Yang style combat Tai Chi and Hatha yoga. So yes, there *would* presumably be *some* physical gains in stamina, flexibility, and strength there... but it's not quite the same as resistance training. Again, it's more akin to martial skill building.

This doesn't mean that he *doesn't* do conditioning training, though.

The only real scan I can find of him actually "pushing his strength" was the one below...

[image]

And I *know* there's a page from the 50s with him lifting some **massively** over-sized dumbbell with one hand in the Fortress of Solitude, but I'm not even sure that counts as canon anymore.

In **Smallville,** especially in the later seasons where he's "The Blur", we see Clark in the Fortress *constantly* pushing himself in mental and physical training, and even combat training, to intensify and master his powers, but that's about the best I've found as being close to canon.

Hell, even in *Lois & Clark: The New Adventures of Superman* we see Clark playing sports, exercising, and in one instance doing boxing training to justify his well built physique, and to "keep himself sharp", as he puts it.

I've found no other references in the comics, though.

So...

**Are there any canonical Post-Crisis or current comics which show Superman training to make himself stronger, faster or enhance his abilities?**

**Note:** Occasions where he has lost his powers don't count.

Comment: I never understood why superheroes are always depicted with bulging muscles. Seems to me they could be scrawny or flabby and paunchy and their superstrength would be the same.

Comment: @user14111 a) it's more "realistic" b) the artists enjoy it c) the readers enjoy it

Comment: @OrangeDog example for points *b* and *c* : **Power-girl** :p

Comment: *Possible dupe?* https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17121/does-superman-have-to-work-out-to-keep-in-shape

Comment: @Shreedhar No, _Similar,_ but not a "Dupe"; that question was about him "keeping fit, but _This_ one specifically asks if he trains to **get stronger or further enhance his abilities.** This is why I included all the examples of him training for _skill building;_ even with his great power, Superman _has_ to consciously improve himself in _some_ way to be a consistently effective hero. I know his alien DNA gives him "near physical perfection", but exercise can _increase_ those capacities, and push his limits making him more effective or powerful. That's what I'm looking for examples of.

Comment: @RussRainford thus the "?" mark.. I wasn't completely sure of it.

Comment: @RussRainford He did stay inside our sun for 15,000 years and emerged with powers levels beyond imagination. so, does this count? https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Kal-El_(DC_One_Million)

Comment: @Shreedhar You mean **Superman:1 million?**  Counts as a power upgrade, but we have no idea if he did any actual _training_ to get those abilities, or was just absorbing radiation until his body "evolved" a new form. I think what I'm looking for is something akin to his training with Mongol, just more... physical, and regular. Much in the way Jennifer Walters physically trained in her human state, then when she "hulks Out" her _base_ She-hulk strength increases. It _is_ fair to say the longer Kal stay under a yellow sun, the stronger he gets, but is there _nothing_ he can do to enhance that?

Answer (score 3):

As a rule, Superman isn't shown to train or work out, aside from occasional sparring sessions with Wonder Woman, which you already mentioned.

In the early 2000s though, there was a storyline where [Mongul II](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Mongul_II_(New_Earth)) (son of the original [post-Crisis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Post-Crisis) [Mongul](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Mongul_I_(New_Earth))) came to Earth to train Superman, to prepare him for the coming threat of [Imperiex](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Imperiex-Prime_(New_Earth)). The training was partly to improve Superman's fighting skills, but they also trained underwater to increase his lung capacity (so he could fly further out into space), and the post-Crisis Superman used super-cold breath for the first time in this storyline (he'd used regular super breath prior to this, but never super-cold breath). Mongul II also suggested that Superman had been subconsciously limiting his power levels in general prior to this storyline, and at one point during the training, Superman said he felt his powers "surging".

[Superman Vol 2 #152](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_2_152)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]